# NLog Writing log within ConfigureServices cause log to lose ${aspnet-request-url} & ${aspnet-mvc-action} throughout the app

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, nlog, ilogger

I use **NLog** for writing logs on my Web API apps, (.Net 6)
And I needed to write to the log inside the **ConfigureServices** method.
Since ILogger is not available at this point, I used this way to write to the log:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, "my data");
```

It works and is written properly to the log,
But the problem is that if this code exists, throughout the application and in **all** subsequent requests, the **${aspnet-request-url}** and **${aspnet-mvc-action}** properties appear empty in the log.
If I remove this code - they appear full in all the requests.

I tried to change the way of writing to the log to something else:

```
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var logger = sp.GetService<ILogger<Startup>>();
logger.LogDebug("my data");
```

It also writes correctly, but the problem with both properties **${aspnet-request-url}** and **${aspnet-mvc-action}** remains the same, both appear **empty**.

My question is:
How is it possible on the one hand to write to the log by **NLog** in the **ConfigureServices** method,
And on the other hand, not to lose the two **${aspnet-request-url}** and **${aspnet-mvc-action}** properties?

p.s.
I want to point out again that they are empty in all the requests that happen **afterwards**,
not only in this writing from the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Guessing `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` makes NLog load the `NLog.config`-file very early, and the `NLog.config`- file is missing `<add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>`. Maybe try this `var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger()` at use the `logger` in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Notice `Startup.cs` and `ConfigureServices` seems to be legacy from NET5 (and older). With NET6 then Microsoft started to sell a different approach: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6

Comment: @RolfKristensen - Yes, I notice now that I am indeed missing `<add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>` in the nlog.config file. When I added it - the problem was solved. Can you post this as an answer?
And indeed you are right, my project was previously in .Net 5 and I upgraded it to .Net 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` very early during application-startup, before `UseNLog()` have automatically registered NLog.Web-extensions, then one is required to do it manually.

Either ensure `NLog.config`-file register extensions like this:

```xml
  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
```

Alternative register extensions from code like this:

```cs
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

When troubleshooting issues with NLog, then it is recommended to use [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and look for clues, along with using `throwConfigExceptions="true"`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Notice `Startup.cs` and `ConfigureServices` seems to be legacy from NET5 (and older). With NET6 then Microsoft started to sell a different approach: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6